# nginx silent log error when main folder does not exist in virtualhost

Tags: nginx

I have a simple config for my site:
When root path does not exist: /var/www/apps/mysite
nginx is not log that error

```
server {

        root /var/www/apps/mysite;
        index index.html;

        server_name mysite.com;
        (... more code)
```

I just can see on:

/var/log/nginx/error.log

just errors like (when my path is correct, errors like files not found)

```
2018/03/23 09:20:36 [error] 18693#18693: *1246 open() "/var/www/apps/mysite/dev/translations.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 78.216.64.172, server: myserver.com, request: "GET /locales/dev/translations.json HTTP/1.1"....
2018/03/23 09:23:09 [notice] 22716#22716: signal process started
common errors when the page is not found;
```

I've tried:  nginx -t  , but display no errors,  of course when I change the path, my site works, but it's no clear this. How it works ngins for the errors? in Apache you need to set the log for every virtualhost file, in nginx looks the log for files not found have a global file log when you have no configuration.

Comment: Do you want to check root path existence when you reload/restart nginx?

Comment: yes; there is a way ?

Comment: You could try lua module to Check for folder in init_by_lua

Comment: thanks, i've tried to look for but it's  a new language I've thought was an error ... thanks anyway

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the log file?

Comment: it' working when I set a existent folder, but my question is nginx have no record errors in log when the folders does not exist, like apache?